# What is causing /api/user on Sanctum to return 401 Unauthenticated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

My API is on `api.domain.test` and my SPA is on `spa.domain.test`.

`spa.domain.test` is a proxy to `localhost:3000` running Next.js server.

`api.domain.test` is your standard folder served out of Valet.

I am running latest **Laravel** and I set up Breeze with the `--api` configuration.

**.env**

```
APP_URL=https://api.domain.test
FRONTEND_URL=https://spa.domain.test
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.test
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Requests to `sanctum/csrf` works. Requests to `/login` works. But not `/api/user`. 401.

I inspected the Chrome network and I see the Cookies are in `Request Headers` too. Still.

I've spent literally a day figuring it out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your domain is added to config/sanctum stateful property as the docs shows in the .env file
[sanctum config](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#configuring-your-first-party-domains)

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS')),
```

Don't forget to cache the config after editing .env file

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: That worked. I was missing the `"` around my `domain.test`